# Generate Public key from Self signed Certificate

Tags: certificates

I have a .crt Self signed certificate generated from salesforce. How can i generate public key from it , i need to provide the public key to be make a call to services

Comment: i figured it out. let me know if anyone does find some issues .

Comment: I think you can post it as an answer here

Comment: OpenSSL> x509 -pubkey -noout -in C:\Integration.crt (WHERE c:\Integration.crt is the path of the file)
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
--------------------------
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: It really depends on where you're going to store it and in what format you need to have it in doesn't it?